# Function of a martingale $=$ semimartingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $X$ be a martingale and $f$ be an arbitrary function from $\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which is twice continuously differentiable with compact support. Why exactly is the process $f(s,X_{s-})$ am semimartingale? Is there any application of Ito? Thanks a lot in advance!